# display parameter on the screen: HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, jsp

I would like to display parameter on the screen, with the below url:
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/hello.view?name=Jane
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/hello.jsp?name=Jane

but the result is "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found"

Here is the servlet:

```
package controller;   

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*; 
import javax.servlet.http.*; 
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final String DEFNAME ="World";

protected void generateResponse 
        (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
             response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); 
             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    String name = request.getParameter("name"); 
    if( name == null || name.length() == 0 ) 
        name = DEFNAME; 
    out.println("Hello, "+name+"!"); 
        out.close(); 
        }

protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException { 
    generateResponse(request, response); 
}

protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    generateResponse(request, response); }
}
```

the jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%! private static final String DEFNAME = "World"; %> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <% 
            String name = request.getParameter("name"); 
            if( name == null || name.length() == 0 ) 
                name = DEFNAME; 
        %> 
        <h2>Hello, <%= name %> !</h2> 
    </body>
</html>
```

the xml:

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello.view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is this your first web application? What is the name of the jsp file? Do you know how to redirect/forward to the jsp?

Comment: This ask was helpful for me, I could solve it. I exchange the servlet name into the project name in the url.